# Specific cross-validation procedure using map() function in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, nested-lists

Suppose I have N train sets all put in a list called dat:

```
dat <- map(tscv$train, ~subset(data, select = .x))
```

Moreover, for each train set, I run lasso using glmnet. For each train set I used 100 values of lambda. For each train set, I have 100 different subset of variables obtained by the following:

```
selected <- map(dat, ~coef.glmnet(glmnet(.x[ , names(Xlagged)],
                                                   .x[ , "errs"], alpha = 1, lambda = lambdas)))
```

The 'selected' is a list of lists. For example, `selected$Training1930$s0` will return the list of the best subset of variables for a particular training set (Training1930) and a particular regularization parameter ("s0"). Now, I would like, to choose the best subset of variables from the list of training sets (dat).

I tried the following:

```
dat |> map(~subset(.x, select = map_depth(selected, 2, ~.)))
```

It returns an error as follows:

> Error in which(!as.logical(j)) :
> 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'

Moroever, I tried to write a function, which works well for specific training set and lambda:

```
a <- function(nom, s){
  return(dat[[nom]][, selected[[nom]][[s]]])
}
mylist <- list()
for(s in names(selected$Training1638)) {
  mylist[[s]] <- print(map(names(dat), ~a(.x, s)))
}
```

The code above seems to solve my problem. However, I do not want to use for loop. Is there any other workarounds?

Reproducible code:

```
    tscv <- list()
    tscv[["train"]] <- list()
    tscv[["train"]][["Training1"]] <- c(1,2,3,4)
    tscv[["train"]][["Training2"]] <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
    set.seed(1)
    full_data <- data.frame(replicate(10,rnorm(10)))
    dat <- map(tscv$train, ~full_data[.x, ])
    
    # Lasso selected features for each train set for 10 different lambdas:
    selected = list(list(list()))
    for (i in paste("s", 1:10, sep = "")) {
      selected[["Training1"]][[i]] <- sample(paste("X", 1:10, sep = ""), 3, rep = TRUE)
      selected[["Training2"]][[i]] <- sample(paste("X", 1:10, sep = ""), 3, rep = TRUE)
    }
```

The purpose is to subset each training set (Training1 and Training 2)
according to the lasso selected variables based on each lambda:

```
    dat |> map(~subset(.x, select = map_depth(selected, 2, ~.)))
```

> Error in x[j] : invalid subscript type 'list'

```
    a <- function(nom, s){
      return(dat[[nom]][, selected[[nom]][[s]]])
    }
    
    # The code below solves my problem and works ok, but I want to avoid for loop:
    mylist <- list()
    for(s in names(selected$Training1)) {
      mylist[[s]] <- map(names(dat), ~a(.x, s))
    }
```

Comment: CAn you show a small reproducible example for testing

Comment: TRY `select` instead of `subset`. also, `map_depth(selected, 2, ~.)` is a list and a list is not names to be selected note that `select/subset` works on a dataframe and not a list

Comment: @akrun I added a reproducible code.